# A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members

Tags: typescript

I have:

```
class CreateYoutubeConversationDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    youtubeId: string;

}
class CreateDirectConversationDto {
    @ApiProperty({ required: false })
    title: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: false })
    description: string;

    @ApiProperty({ required: true })
    createdByUserId: string;
}

type CreateConvo = typeof CreateDirectConversationDto | typeof CreateYoutubeConversationDto

export class CreateConversationDto implements CreateConvo { }
```

But this gives me an error at `CreateConvo`:

```
A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members
```

What does that mean? I have all the types declared.

Comment: It's because `CreateConvo` is a union and it's ambiguous as to how to enforce an implementation of a union type. You should surely specify a different type, but which will depend on what you imagine `CreateConversationDto` as. Does it have all four of the example properties? Or only the properties from one type or the other? Or you don't know until you instantiate it?

Comment: I want it to be either of those: Direct / YouTube

Comment: So if it had tile, it shouldn’t have youtubeId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's change `implements` for `extends` for a moment.
When if you'll write

```
class CreateConversationDto extends CreateConvo {}
```

it's not only TS compiler but even a JS-engine, which doesn't care about types so much, will be really confused about what should be considered as a prototype for this class.

Now let's get back to `implements`, and let's imagine that such a type can be created. But let's add another level to hierachy:

```
class CreateConversationDto implements CreateConvo {}
class X extends CreateConversationDto {} // even without types this class can't be created
```

And we're back at square 1.

You can create **union types** but not **union classes**.

---

Is there any particular reason why you might not be happy with this variant:

```
export class CreateYoutubeConversationDto { youtubeId: string }
export class CreateDirectConversationDto  { title: string; ... }
export type CreateConvo = CreateDirectConversationDto | CreateYoutubeConversationDto
...
function some_f(arg: CreateConvo) {
    if (arg instanceof CreateYoutubeConversationDto) return arg.youtubeId
    else return arg.title
}
```